# What's the name of the little plastic bolt (?) that is used by a passanger/driver to lock the door from the inside?

Tags: body, body-work

I'm talking about a (for example) seat/skoda/vw car, in which (un)locking the car from the inside requires the driver to press a locking bolt.

Two of them broke in my car and I'm trying to find a replacement online but I just can't seem to find a name for them and/or a place where I can buy a replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your best bet is to search for [door lock buttons](http://motors.shop.ebay.com/__?_from=R40&_trksid=p3841.m39.l1313&_nkw=door%20lock%20buttons&_sacat=&rvr_id=271361339868&clk_rvr_id=271361339868&MT_ID=335&crlp=7494972256_9887&tt_encode=raw&geo_id=491&keyword=door%20lock%20buttons&adgroup_id=774139996).  Using that search, I see a long list of parts that include the manual push buttons that you describe.